# Repeating decimals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> For a certain positive integer $n$ less than $1000$, the decimal equivalent of $\frac{1}{n}$ is $0.\overline{abcdef}$, a repeating decimal of period $6$, and the decimal equivalent of $\frac{1}{n+6}$ is $0.\overline{wxyz}$, a repeating decimal of period $4$. In which interval does $n$ lie? $\textbf{(A)}\ [1,200] \qquad
> \textbf{(B)}\ [201,400] \qquad
> \textbf{(C)}\ [401,600] \qquad
> \textbf{(D)}\ [601,800] \qquad
> \textbf{(E)}\ [801,999] $

All I have for this is $n \mid 10^6 - 1$ and $n+ 6 \mid 10^4 - 1$. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You have $n+6 | 9 \cdot 11 \cdot101$

But if $n+6 | 10^a -1 $ where $a<4 $, then $\frac {1}{n+6} $will have $a$ repeating digits. So checking cases we get

$n+6 = 101, 303 $ or $909$

Now we have $n | 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 7 \cdot27 \cdot37$

So $ n= 297$  is the only solution

EDIT:

$ \frac{1}{297} =0. \overline{003367}$

$ \frac {1}{303} =0. \overline{0033}$